# changing responsive breakpoint for mobile version in responsive css - but where? (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Just checked my site http://www.traumbad-muenchen.de in this tool http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ using the tablet setting Apple IPad 768x1024.

For this size the navigation menu seems to be too big, cause it is displayed in two lines. Thats why I would like to set the responsive breakpoint to 800px width so that instead of the navigation menu the navigation for mobile version is displayed (≡ menu symbol on the top, right corner).

What do I have to change in the responsive.css to get this done?

Thx for your tips.
BR
Heidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to change in **responsive.css** but instead you will be modifying the main style sheet @ [style.css](http://traumbad-muenchen.de/wp-content/themes/hueman/style.css?ver=3.9.3)

Simply replace all the instances of **719px** to **800px**

[image]

Now replace all the instances of **720px** with **801px**

---

You can copy paste the whole style sheet in a notepad ( or any similar tool ) and then start replacing just the **719px** part and **720px** and you should be good.

Comment: Hi NMindz! Thank you so much, did it like you said and it works pretty fine!